# Flutter: Passing data through constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am currently learning and I can't figure out why I can't pass this data back through the constructor.

Main Screen:

```
    TitleTextField(
                      textFieldOnSaved: textFieldFinalValue,
                      hintText: "Add title here",
                    ),

     createLocationPostInFirestore(
          {String mediaUrl,
          String description,
          double heightRestriction,
          double widthRestriction}) {
        locationPostRef
            .document(currentUser.id)
            .collection("user_location_posts")
            .document(postId)
            .setData({
          "postId": postId,
          "ownerId": currentUser.id,
          "username": currentUser.username,
]
          "test_title": textFieldFinalValue,
        });
      }

      handlePostSubmit() async {
        setState(() {
          isUploading = true;
        });
        await compressStoryImage();
        String mediaUrl = await uploadStoryImage(locationImageFile);
        createLocationPostInFirestore(
          mediaUrl: mediaUrl,
          heightRestriction: heightRestrictionValue,
        );
        SnackBar snackbar = SnackBar(
          content: Text("Location Uploaded"),
        );
        _addNewLocationScreenScaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);
        setState(() {
          isUploading = false;
          postId = Uuid().v4();
        });
      }
```

And this is the widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TitleTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController handleTextEditingController;
  final String textFieldOnSaved;
  final String hintText;
  TitleTextField(
      {this.handleTextEditingController, this.textFieldOnSaved, this.hintText});

  void _getTextfield(String textFieldOnSaved) {
    textFieldOnSaved = textFieldOnSaved;
  }

  _TitleTextFieldState createState() => _TitleTextFieldState();
}

class _TitleTextFieldState extends State<TitleTextField> {
  final TextEditingController handleTextEditingController =
      TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
          hintText: widget.hintText,
        ),
        controller: handleTextEditingController,
        onChanged: (String textFieldValue) {
          setState(() {
            widget._getTextfield(textFieldValue);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is get the value from the text field and pass it back through the constructor and then back to the main screen so I can then save the value to Firestore.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where does textFieldFinalValue gets instantiated (which you use in TitleTextField) and is this reference of type TextEditingController?

Answer (score 1):

I am a beginner but perhaps I can help you.
I installed the package shared preference for this. 
I have used it also for my app.

The package is here: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences#-installing-tab-

I have a file: formula.dart where I have all the the formules and variables I need. Here I have imported:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:math';
```

I have also there this variables:

```
bool weight = true;
int mixingRatio = 50;
int liquidGravity = 105;
```

Then I have a way to store the values, the user put in:

```
updateValues() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setInt('mixingRatio', mixingRatio);
  prefs.setInt('liquidGravity', liquidGravity);
  prefs.setBool('weight', weight);
}
```

This values can you also load, I have this only on the first page I load. It seems that it is then in its memory, You have to put it directly under the class:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadValues();
  }

loadValues() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  mixingRatio = (prefs.getInt('mixingRatio') ?? 50);
  liquidGravity = (prefs.getInt('liquidGravity') ?? 105);
  weight = (prefs.getBool('weight') ?? true);
}
```

You see, it pick up the value that is stored. If there is no value, it puts in the value, given after the ?? .

Good luck with it!!!